# How to manage multiple query on onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I would like to manage multiple query results on real time display

- On query 1 filter the toUser
- On query 2 filter the user._id

then marge and order by `createAt`

below is my code.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerLeft: () => (
            <View style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
                <Avatar
                    rounded
                    source={{
                        uri: auth?.currentUser?.photoURL,
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        ),
        headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{
                marginRight: 10
            }}
                onPress={signOutNow}
            >
                <Text>logout</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    })
    
    //const q = query(collection(db, 'chats'), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
    const q = query(collection(db, 'chats'), where("toUser", "in", [auth?.currentUser?.email, "test@aa.com"]));
    const q2 = query(collection(db, 'chats'), where("user._id", "in", [auth?.currentUser?.email, "test@aa.com"]));

    console.log(q);
    //const q = db.collection("chats").where("toUser", "==", currentUser).orderBy('createAt','desc')
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => setMessages(
        snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            _id: doc.data()._id,
            createdAt: doc.data().createdAt.toDate(),
            text: doc.data().text,
            user: doc.data().user,
            toUser: doc.data().toUser,

        }))
    ));

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
}, [navigation]);
```

It seem only support one query on the onSnapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `onSnapshot` indeed takes only a single query (or document reference or collection reference).

If you need to get snapshots for multiple queries, you'll need to call `onSnapshot` for each of those.

If you want to show the results of those queries in a single list in the UI, you will have to merge the results in your application code.

You can see if you can change/augment your data model to allow getting the same results with a single query. For example, I typically have a `participants` array field in my docs with the UIDs of all participants, which I can then use in a single query to get the same results as you get with the two queries.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your comment, so that if I merge the results, the can't use the onSnapshot for readtime display right? need to found out other way to display the message.

Or I will thing how to have participants array filed in my docs with UIDs. Thanks~